# What is the use of recursive type bound in this case

Tags: java, generics

I have the following piece of code

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(List<T> list){
    Iterator<T> iter = list.iterator();
    ...
    // code for finding the max element in the list
    ...
 }
```

My question is, what is the need for the recursive type bound in this case? As far as my understanding, `T extends Comparable < T >` means that, `T` can be compared only with `T` itself. This comes from the fact that, `Class 'T' implements Comparable<T>` and so,

```
class MyClass implements Comparable<MyClass>{
}
```

If I am wrong here, feel free to correct me.

So now coming to the actual doubt, why do we need to specify `< T extends Comparable < T > >` ? Any ways the argument `List<T>` list is going to contain the elements of same type. i.e., suppose I pass a parameter of type `List < MyClass2 >` , then all the elements are going to be of same type, i.e. `MyClass2`..

So what is the implication of recursive type bound?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can make a class that is comparable on some other class.

Comment: For maximum flexibility, you probably actually want `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Comment: Best description given by Joshua Bloch. Check this video to get the best clarification. Topic starts at 22:00 [Effective Java - Still Effective After All These Years](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1vQf4qyMXg)

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need to specify `<T extends Comparable<T>>`? Because Comparable does not require that an implementing class be comparable with itself. You could in theory write something like

```
class Circle extends Shape implements Comparable<Integer> {
    ...
}
```

Since Comparable itself does not make that restriction, you have to on your end when writing the function. However, the given bound is more restrictive than you need it to be. You could make the call

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(List<T> list) {
    ...
}
```

That would mean `T` is comparable to some superclass of itself. The reason you want this is given in the Fruit example of rgettman. `T` is still always comparable to itself, but the comparable does not have to be defined with respect to `T` itself.

Comment: "Because Comparable does not require that an implementing class be comparable with itself." And, in fact, can't. That's not possible to express in Generics, and it is also never needed.

Answer (score 3):

You may have a class hierarchy that forces subclasses to be `Comparable` to a supertype.  For example, you may have

```
class Fruit extends Comparable<Fruit>
```

so every piece of `Fruit` is comparable to another piece of `Fruit`.  Then you have

```
class Apple extends Fruit ...
class Banana extends Fruit ...
```

Each subclass is a `Fruit`, so they are all `Comparable<Fruit>`, and not `Comparable<Apple>` and not `Comparable<Banana>`.

This allows you to find the maximum `Fruit` (probably a bad example, what's the maximum Fruit?) in a `List<Apple>`:

```
List<Apple> apples = getApples();
Fruit maximum = max(apples);
```

without it having to be a `List<Fruit>`.

As has been pointed out in comments, it's better for the `max` method to be:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(List<T> list){
```

So that each of the following works:

```
List<Apple> apples = getApples();
Apple maxAppleOfApples = max(apples);
Fruit maxFruitOfApples = max(apples);

List<Banana> bananas = getBananas();
Banana maxBananaOfBananas = max(bananas);
Fruit maxFruitOfBananas = max(bananas);

List<Fruit> fruits = getFruit();
Fruit maxFruitOfFruit = max(fruits);
```

Comment: Okay I get it 90%. Just one more clarification. The type parameter goes like this.. <T extends Comparable<T>>.. So in this case, T must be same on both the places, i.e. the first T and the second T inside Comparable. But this doesn't hold in the example you have given. For your example, the first T contains Apples / Bananas and the second T holds Fruits.. HOw can the same type parameter T contain two different values?

Comment: @rgettman That is not going to work. If `T` is Fruit, then you can't pass in a `List<Apple>`, only a `List<Fruit>`. You have to either make it `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` or `List<? extends T>`, or both.

Comment: @ILMTitan Yeah, I saw that after I posted it too.  Please see my update.  You're right; `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` is the solution here.